# Flutter List Tile inherits theme from themedata?

Tags: flutter, listtile

Does ListTile widgets automatically inherit the listTile theme data declared in the app's theme in flutter?
I gave a shape in the themedata, but it is not reflecting in the ui

Comment: can you please share the code so that we can resolve your error..??

Comment: *"Does ListTile widgets automatically inherit the listTile theme data declared in the app's theme in flutter?"* - check [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/097d3313d8/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/list_tile.dart#L1149) and search for `tileTheme.shape`